# Good books that deal with ethics and its dimensions

Tags: ethics, reference-request

Can some one name me a good book that deals with ethics and its dimensions? It should deal with the basics of ethics with examples or maybe some case studies analysis.

Comment: You should tell us a little more about the specific concern you're after and what you've found already. That said I might suggest something like Buber's *I and Thou*, which should help provide context and motivations for modern ethical inquiry. (It's also good preparation for Levinas whose *Totality and Infinity* might be another suggestion.)

Comment: I know some might snort derisively but have you considered the Bible?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you require a theistic ground, Peter Singer's work is strong, insightful, and specific.  I'd recommend *Writings on an Ethical Life,* *The Life You Can Save,* and *Animal Liberation.* You can deductively apply the principles he develops to many concrete situations.

Comment: thanks for valuable information...can you please tell me some standard book on global and Indian  moral thinkers, leaders , administrator.